# How can I strengthen my identification of Luke Hallam and his wife Ann in 18th century Nottinghamshire?

Tags: 18th-century, marriage-records, nottinghamshire

My ancestors John Brooks and Ann Hallam married in November 1798 in Clifton with Glapton, Nottinghamshire. The couple had 8 children baptised between 1800 and 1813. (All sources except where specified are the Marriage, Baptism and Burial Indices prepared by Nottingham Family History Society).

In the 1841 census Ann is shown as being 66 years old; her death certificate (1848) shows her as 75 years old. These two data points suggest a date of birth between November 1772 and June 1775.

There are 4 Ann Hallams baptised in Clifton with Glapton between  1769 and 1776; two of these can be eliminated as they died (a) in 1769 and (b) in 1829.  This leaves Ann Hallam daughter to Robert Hallam and Ann Wilkinson (baptised 1770) and Ann Hallam, daughter of Luke Hallam and his wife Ann (baptised 1773).   If 'my' Ann was baptised in 1770, she would have been at least 30 when she had her first child (assuming baptisms took place close to birth), which is old by the standards of the day. (The Ann baptised in 1773 would have been circa 27, which is also a little on the shady side).

Based on the data available, I've identified Ann daughter of Luke and Ann as my likely ancestor, and now want to move on to identifying Luke and Ann.

The name Luke Hallam is not common in the Clifton with Glapton Parish Registers. It appears at the baptism of his 6 children with Ann between 1773 and 1783; at his marriage to Mary Stevens in August 1803 (Ann was buried in March 1803); and at his burial in December 1820.  None of these records give his age. When I visited Clifton churchyard in 2009, I was unable to locate the graves of many Hallams and definitely not these two.

Ann (his wife) only appears in the registers at the baptism of her children, and at her burial in 1803. None of these records give her age.

However, their first child (Ann) was baptised in 1773; assuming this took place within 1-2 years of their marriage, I can estimate a marriage date of 1771-1772; and if they were older than 18 when married, I can estimate birth dates of 1753 or earlier.

Searching the Nottinghamshire Family History Society Marriage Index 1533-1929 (which has excellent coverage), there are only 2 marriages of a Luke Hallam to an Ann[e] in Nottinghamshire -- one in 1694 (too early) and one in 1772 (Luke Hallam to Anne Gervas on 20 Apr 1772 in the parish of Plumtree.)  Plumtree is 5 miles from Clifton so the geography is not a problem; and the date ties up with the baptism of their first child in December 1773.

However, it is possible that they married outside Nottinghamshire...

A Luke Hallam married Ann Mee on 1 Feb 1768 in Barrow upon Soar, Leicestershire (they were both 'of this parish'), but they were baptising children in Barrow Upon Soar in the same period as Luke and Ann in Clifton, so can be eliminated. There are no other marriages between Luke Hallam (and variants) and Ann (and variants) between 1750 and 1800 in any online index I can find.

Are there any other records I could consult which would strengthen the case for Luke Hallam and Ann Gervas being the parents of Ann Hallam baptised 1773 in Cifton with Glapton? Or do I have sufficient evidence to make the case already?